# Не устанавливается pyinstaller.Выводит ошибку:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь установить pyinstaller через pip,но не получаеться.

Cсылка на текст что выводить:https://yadi.sk/d/qx7qS_NzP2jjhA

Python:3.8.4

Cистема:Windows 10 pro

Тип системы:64 бит

Текст что выводить:

```
C:\Python>pip install pyinstaller

Collecting pyinstaller

  Downloading PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz (3.5 MB)

     |████████████████████████████████| 3.5 MB 450 kB/s

  Installing build dependencies ... done

  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done

    Preparing wheel metadata ... error

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

     command: 'c:\python\python.exe' 'c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\E1AC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpko1f2grb'

         cwd: C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cdppc0b5\pyinstaller

    Complete output (36 lines):

    running dist_info

    creating C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info

    writing C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO

    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

    writing entry points to C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt

    writing requirements to C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info\requires.txt

    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt

    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:

    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)

    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'

    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'

    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'

    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

    creating 'C:\Users\Валентин Баранов\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-x7m4tqa8\PyInstaller.dist-info'

    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python.exe' 'c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\E1AC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpko1f2grb' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Приведите используемую команду и ошибку текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Команда:pip install pyinstaller  Ошибка:ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python.exe' 'c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\E1AC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpko1f2grb' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: @Валентит спасибо, так конечно же понятнее стало

Comment: Вот ссылка на txt фаил:https://yadi.sk/d/qx7qS_NzP2jjhA это он выводит.

Comment: Какая версия питона? Какая ваша система: Винда, линукс?

Comment: Версия питона:3.8.4 Cистема:винда 10 64бит

Comment: Всё это в вопросе указывайте (кнопка править)

Comment: Прикрепи текст в вопрос текстом

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте `pip install wheel`
или

```
pip3 install wheel
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь но я уже переустоновил пайтон